# Matching two file paths containing wildcard characters

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

I have the following two File Paths in Robot Framework working on Python 2.7

1. `value1 = c:\program files (x86)\abc\foldername\14.2.222.0000.101\scripts\bin\filename.exe`
2. `value2 = c:\program files (x86)\abc\folder name\\*\filename.exe`

I want to match the above two paths using Regex.
PS: `14.2.222.0000.101\scripts\bin` in `value1` can be dynamic and therefor `value2` contains a wildcard character.

I tried the below code

```
Should Match Regexp ${value1}   ${value2}
```

Comment: paths are not regular expressions, and treating them as such may yield surprising results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @BryanOakley . Any other suggestion to match the two strings?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fnmatch.html

Comment: If you want to use regex escape all backslashes, the dot and the brackets with an additional \ And replace * with .*

Comment: I already tried with something like
```c:\\program files \(x86\)\\abc\\folder name\\.*\\filename.exe```
but is does not work. It was mentioned in one of the answer but seems like someone deleted it :)